# To get array keys if value is not zero

Tags: php, array-key

I have array like and used array_keys to get keys:

```
$arr =  array(  1 => 1,
        2 => 3,
        3 => 2,
        5 => 0,
        6 => 0 );

$new_arr = array_keys($arr);
```

Now, I want to get array_keys if value is not zero. How can i do this?

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run `array_filter` on your array before you get the keys; that removes the 0 values and you only get the keys you need.

```
$new_arr = array_keys(array_filter($arr));
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all elements with values before passing array for `array_keys`:

```
NULL
null
''
0
```

With the following:

```
array_filter($array, function($var) {
  // Remove all empty values defined in the above list.
  return !is_empty($var);
});
```

Comment: That callback is not needed, will do even without it. Its the default behavior: `If no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed. `

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky, that is a good learning for me. This is why I love stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$num_array = array(1,2,3,4,0,0);
$zero_val  = array_keys($num_array,!0);
print_r($zero_val);
```